# Bold Emails in Job Listings

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function to bold e-mails in my job offers (the post type is job_listing), but it's not working and it's not giving errors at all.

```
    function bold_emails_in_job_listings($content) {
    if (is_singular('job_listing')) {
        $content = preg_replace_callback('/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b/', function($matches) {
            return '<strong>' . $matches[0] . '</strong>';
        }, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'bold_emails_in_job_listings');
```

What do you guys think I'm failing?
Regards.

Comment: if you replace your `preg_replace_callback` call with `$content = 'it works';` does it replace the content or does the content stay the same?

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell - It seems not working. But if I change the is_singular function to 'post', it works on the blog posts. Super weird, right? I already checked twice, and the 'job_listing' is really the post-type name.

Comment: is the page you're showing these on actually a job listing single page? Or is it a post that has a template that runs a new query to display job listings? `is_singular` isn't referring to the post the content belongs to, it's referring to the current main query, so if you're trying to show a list of job listings in a sidebar of a post, the main query is for a post, not your job listings

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your code as follows to correctly bold email addresses in job listings:

```php
function bold_emails_in_job_listings($content) {
    if (is_singular('job_listing')) {
        $content = preg_replace_callback('/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\b/', function($matches) {
            return '<strong>' . $matches[0] . '</strong>';
        }, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'bold_emails_in_job_listings');
```

The change I made is in the regular expression pattern. I replaced `[A-Z|a-z]` with `[A-Za-z]` to correctly match email addresses in both uppercase and lowercase letters. This should make your function work as expected, and it will bold email addresses in job listings.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help, but the problem didn't was the code. The problem was the job_listing doesn't associate properly with the job posts.